# Replace coma with dot - Google Sheet does not find replace function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace

Google sheets does not find the function replace.
What is wrong in my code?

The error message is:

[image]

```
function uptimeCheck() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXX");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tabellenblatt1');
var uptime_string = sheet.getRange("E5").getValue();
  var uptime_zahl = uptime_string.replace(",", ".");
  //Utilities.sleep(1120000);//hier wird acht Minuten gewartet, Zeit in Millisekunden
var uptime_new_string = sheet.getRange("E5").getValue();
  var uptime_new_zahl = uptime_new_string.replace(/,/g , ".");

  if (uptime_zahl != uptime_new_zahl)
  {
    var emailAddress = 'XXX';
    var subject = 'Der Bot läuft nicht';
    var message = 'Die uptime hat sich nicht verändert';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,message);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The error message clearly states that there is no `replace()` method in **object 1.3...**. This means that the value passed to the `uptime_string` is not of type `string` (most likely it is of type `number` in your case) which doesn't have the `replace()` method.

**Solution**

Ensure that the value is a string with `toString()` method (this only one of possible ways to ensure the value is a `string`, e.g. you might want to treat `Date` values differently, etc):

```
uptime_string = sheet.getRange("E5").getValue().toString();
```

**Notes**

1. You might want to do the same with the `uptime_new_string` as it might suffer from the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. Thats helps a lot :) But the value in E5 gets updated every 15 seconds and i gave Google 5 minutes to wait. The Value does not change if the google sheet is not opened.

How can i get an updated Value from E5 even if the sheet is not openend?

Comment: Hi @Peter008! Not sure if I understand what you mean - your second question isn't related to the issue? Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Please, if this is a separate issue, post it as a new question (and link to this one for context if needed)